# Download Android Droidtext library for PDF?

Tags: android

I need please a useful site for **Android Droidtext library** that for PDF functions in android?! I note that all sites are broken!?

I need it to can create PDF document and be able to write on it in Android ...

Many Thanks ,,

Comment: My problem solved by download this library which DynamicPDF.jar from this link please:   [https://www.assembla.com/code/zapisyUG/subversion/nodes/zapisWAR/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/DynamicPDF.jar?_format=raw&rev=133] @Michael, laalto, Selvin, Padma Kumar, S.L. Barth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is a link only answer,but since the official site link is broken and knowing that this may help a lot of people. i am posting a link. 
You can go here and download [droidText.0.0.2.jar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d5ra9qyb1bgd9t/droidText.0.2.jar?dl=0)  or [here](https://code.google.com/p/beratungs-app/source/browse/BeratungsKonfigurator/libs/droidText.0.2.jar?spec=svn36&r=36)

Comment: The link is not working. Can you provide another link?

Comment: First link has been updated,please try now

Comment: __+1 for maintaining the link. *iText* is great but i'm just a hungry engineer